# modal.confirm in salesforce?

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce

```
if ((Modal.confirm && Modal.confirm('some text here')) || (!Modal.confirm && window.confirm('same text here'))) navigateToUrl('some link here','DETAIL','submit');
```

I have the above code on the onClick condition of a button. Just wanted to know what does the term modal.confirm and window.confirm mean? Also how does clicking on 'Ok' in the popup navigate me to that link, as there's no mention of 'Ok' in the above condition?

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0):

window.confirm() is the basic (ok, cancel) alert, if you want to catch the "ok" button you have to do something like:

```
var result = window.confirm('You sure ?');
    if (result) {
        // Ok case
    } else {
        // Cancel case  
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm